# Assemble: How can I generate pages from json/yaml?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, assemble

Is there a way to generate pages from json/yaml if you provide a layout? I thought this was possible, but can't find in docs.

This is currently being tracked here in GitHub: http://webb.li/QjTX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `options.pages` feature has been implemented, you can add pages like this:

```
options: {
  pages: {
    "about": {
      "data": {
        "title": "About"
      },
      "content": "Content for {{title}}"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

We aren't supporting automatic loading of a json/yml file, but you can do this inside your Gruntfile and add the object to `options.pages` that way...

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({

    // package.json
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    assemble: {
      options: {
        flatten: true,
        layoutdir: 'src/layouts',
        assets: 'dest/assets'
      },
      blog: {
        options: {
          engine: 'handlebars',
          layout: 'post.hbs',
          site: {
            title: 'This is my Blog'
          },
          pages: grunt.file.readJSON('pages.json')
        },
        files: { 'dest/': ['src/index.hbs'] }
      }
    }
  });

  // Load npm plugins to provide necessary tasks.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('assemble');

  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['assemble']);

};
```

This example uses the `post.hbs` file as the layout for any pages defined in the `pages.json` file. It will also build a page for the `index.hbs` specified in the files src array. Right now, the files dest/src is required so Assemble knows where to write the files, but I think we'll add that to the options, or the page object so it can be run without the files object.

Comment: note that this refers to [grunt-assemble](https://github.com/assemble/grunt-assemble), the grunt plugin for [assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble), which has a completely different API now