# How to create pages from data using Assemble in Gulp?

Tags: gulp, assemble

I'm currently using Gulp as the build tool for a project. One of the Gulp tasks uses Assemble to assemble the Handlebars pages/layouts into HTML:

```
var assemble = require('assemble')();

gulp.task('assemble', ['clean'], function () {
    assemble.partials('./partials/**/*.hbs');
    assemble.layouts('./layouts/**/*.hbs');
    assemble.pages('./pages/**/*.hbs');

    loadHelpers(); // Calls assemble.helpers(...) on some Handlebars helpers

    var data = require('./hbs_context.json');
    assemble.data(data);
    assemble.data({root: process.cwd()});

    return assemble.toStream('managements')
        .pipe(assemble.renderFile())
        .pipe(plugins.extname()) // Converts .hbs to .html
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/'));
});
```

I've come upon a part of my project which requires multiple pages created from an array of data, where each object of the array would be a context for a separate page.

This same problem has been brought up and answered many times:

[How can I generate multiple pages from a JSON file with Assemble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502081/how-can-i-generate-multiple-pages-from-a-json-file-with-assemble)

[Assemble: How can I generate pages from json/yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153160/assemble-how-can-i-generate-pages-from-json-yaml)

[grunt assemble multiple files from one datafile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934362/grunt-assemble-multiple-files-from-one-datafile)

https://github.com/assemble/assemble/issues/236

https://github.com/assemble/assemble/issues/184

https://github.com/assemble/assemble/pull/234

However, all the solutions provided use Grunt options, and I can't figure out how to do the same thing in Gulp. So, is there an equivalent way to do this in Gulp?

Answer (score 0):

I have just started to set up Assemble and it seems that it runs without problems in gulp. This [depreciated NPM plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-assemble) showed how it is done, notice the difference:

Assemble with Gulp

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
var extname = require('gulp-extname');
var assemble = require('assemble');
var app = assemble();
 
gulp.task('load', function(cb) {
  app.partials('templates/partials/*.hbs');
  app.layouts('templates/layouts/*.hbs');
  app.pages('templates/pages/*.hbs');
  cb();
});
 
gulp.task('assemble', ['load'], function() {
  return app.toStream('pages')
    .pipe(app.renderFile())
    .pipe(htmlmin())
    .pipe(extname())
    .pipe(app.dest('site'));
});
 
gulp.task('default', ['assemble']);
```

Assemble without Gulp

```js
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
var extname = require('gulp-extname');
var assemble = require('assemble');
var app = assemble();
 
app.task('load', function(cb) {
  app.partials('templates/partials/*.hbs');
  app.layouts('templates/layouts/*.hbs');
  app.pages('templates/pages/*.hbs');
  cb();
});
 
app.task('assemble', ['load'], function() {
  return app.toStream('pages')
    .pipe(app.renderFile())
    .pipe(htmlmin())
    .pipe(extname())
    .pipe(app.dest('site'));
});
 
app.task('default', ['assemble']);
```

Assemble can use all Gulp plugins with no problems.

If you want to learn more, check out this lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9kOy2e5koE

So far I have found out that you can insert data like so:

```
app.task('load', function(cb) {
  app.data('templates/data/*.json');
  app.partials('templates/partials/*.hbs');
  app.layouts('templates/layouts/*.hbs');
  app.pages('templates/pages/*.hbs');
  cb();
});
```

It has to be first in the "load" task.